# Can't change material of anything?

Tags: materials

Title says it all. I can not add/change the material/color of ANYTHING.The entire page where materials should be is just completely blank.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzzeY.jpg

Comment: You can upload to imgur or some other file sharing site and someone will add the image to your question for you.

Comment: Scroll up the tab where material settings should be. In the top there would be big button New.

Comment: on the far right of the screen there is a bar showing that you are at the bottom of the panel, scroll up to show the settings.

Comment: I feel so stupid now XD Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score -1):

You Have to scroll up lol, you can see that you Have the scrollbar down.